Saving file and attaching to email
I created code to save a PDF into a specified folder, attach it to an email and send.
Sub Saveaspdfandsend()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20230130
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet

xFolder = "H:\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXXX\XXXXXXX\" + Range("N1") + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    
    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .To = "my email"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = Range("N1") + ".pdf"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        '.Send
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

It highlights this line when I debug:
xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

The range of the print to PDF is based on the worksheet defined print area and how many pages wide and how many pages tall. I want it to choose the Print to PDF defined range based on the Pivot table (which can change in size) based on the pivot table name of FinalPivot.
I tried to change the code to pick up the pivot table name but was unsuccessful.

Don´t you have an error message? What's your xFolder value when you try to export? Or to what value does Range("N1") evaluates to?

Code highlighted in yellow means that is as far as it got and it paused waiting for you to press either F5 or F8 etc. If there is a red dot in the left margin it means there is a breakpoint there. However, occasionally you will get code stopping where a breakpoint used to be or for no apparent reason. These are my notes:
(in 2nd comment as no more room here. Not posting as solution as does not address your remaining problems)

Things to try

Close Excel and reopen. Try to run again. Sometimes works
Put a breakpoint on that line (F9) and take it off again. Try to run again. Sometimes works
Debug, Clear All Breakpoints (Ctrl-Shift-F9). Try to run again. Usually works
Make a minor change (e.g. delete a character, type it back in, click onto another line). Debug, Compile VBA Project. Save Workbook and Exit. Try to run again. Never known this to not work, but it's a pain


To print only the pivot table: xSht.PageSetup.PrintArea = xSht.PivotTables("FinalPivot").TableRange2.Address If that does not print then if you try to print manually is "Microsoft print to PDF" present in the printer list?

Thanks Alex, where abouts in the code would I put this and do I need to delete anything ?

I'll repost my comments here to cover your first problem...
Code highlighted in yellow means that is as far as it got and it paused waiting for you to press either F5 or F8 etc.
If there is a red dot in the left margin it means there is a breakpoint there. However, occasionally you will get code stopping where a breakpoint used to be or for no apparent reason. These are my notes on things to try

Close Excel and reopen. Try to run again. Sometimes works
Put a breakpoint on that line (F9) and take it off again. Try to run again. Sometimes works
Debug, Clear All Breakpoints (Ctrl-Shift-F9). Try to run again. Usually works
Make a minor change (e.g. delete a character, type it back in, click onto another line). Debug, Compile VBA Project. Save Workbook and Exit. Try to run again. Never known this to not work, but it's a pain

I've run your code and it successfully created a PDF, attached it to an email but did not send it - try these solutions

Did you continue to run the code or did it stay sat on the yellow line? If the latter then follow the steps above and re-run OR just hit F5 to continue running
Does the folder structure you are trying to save to actually already exist? Check the contents of xFolder and make sure that file is being saved where you think it is - e.g. are you missing a \, do all the subfolders exist. If not then create them either manually or in code, or correct your H:\XXX bit.
It doesn't send the email because you have commented out the .Send - remove the comment and it will work
See comment from @Alex K. for the Pivot table problem

